# unexpected behaviour of pointer after successive calls to function which returns a reference to a member of class

Tags: c++, list, pointers

C++ beginner here. I have read that it is not good practice to return a reference to a local variable of a function due to it going out of scope when the function returns. I understand why this is but I am wondering if it is okay to return a reference to a member of a class.

I am writing a simple implementation of a graph as an adjacency list and have a function called `insertNode` which adds a `Node` object to a member variable of type `std::vector<Node>` on a class `Graph` and returns a reference to the node which was just added to the vector.

The implementation of `insertNode` is:

```
//graph.cpp
Node* Graph::insertNode(Node n) {
    this->nodeArray.push_back(n);
    return &(this->nodeArray.back());
}
```

Where the Graph class is:

```
//graph.h
class Graph {
private:
    vector<Node> nodeArray; 
public:
    // Constructor
    Graph();
    Node* insertNode(Node n);
    vector<Node> getNodes(); 
    void connectNodes(Node* a, Node* b, int edgeWeight);
};
```

and the Node class is:

```
//node.h
class Node {
private:
    list<Edge> edgeList;
    string nodeName; 
    pair <int, int> coordinates;
public:
    Node();
    Node(string nodeName, int x, int y);
    void setNodeName(string nodeName);
    void setXY(int x, int y);
    void insertEdge(Edge edgeToAdd);
    void removeEdge(Edge fromEdge, Edge toEdge);
    list<Edge> getEdgeList();
};
```

I have implemented `insertGraph` in this way as I need to return a pointer to the node which was added to be used in `connectNodes` - a function which creates an `Edge` object between two Nodes and updates a list of edges on each node where the source node and destination node of the edge are just pointers to the Nodes themselves.

The problem I am running into is that in the following code as part of a test case, when I first call `insertNode` I can see in my IDE's watch that it returns the pointer to the node which was added and the contents at this address is correct, however on a successive call of `insertNode` taking a different Node object, the first pointer which was returned seems to get modified.

```
//test.cpp
SECTION("connects two nodes with an edge") {
        Graph g = Graph();
        Node a = Node("Johannesburg", 5, 10);
        Node b = Node("Cape Town", 26, 10);

        Node* aptr = g.insertNode(a); //first call
        Node* bptr = g.insertNode(b); //second call
        g.connectNodes(aptr, bptr, 1);
```

After the first call to `insertNode` passing `a`, `aptr` looks like this:
[image: contents of aptr after first call to insertNode]
After the second call to `insertNode` passing `b`, `aptr` changes to this:
[image: contents of aptr after second call to insertNode]

Why does this behaviour occur? Which cardinal sin of bad C++ code have I committed and what would be a better way to implement the `insertNode` function if this is indeed the problem?

Comment: `insertNode` is calling `push_back`, which can reallocate the vector storage, invalidating existing pointers into the the vector data. After `b` is inserted `aptr` might not be valid anymore (which seems to be your case).

Comment: Why does `insertNode()` return `Node*` and not `Node&` when you say it returns a reference?

Comment: Following my previous comment above: you can consider to make `nodeArray` a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>>` and return the `shared_ptr` from `insertNode`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller probably my use of wording is wrong. I mean that it returns the memory address of the Node which was pushed back to the vector.

Comment: *Which cardinal sin of bad C++ code have I committed?*  The sin of holding onto a non-owning pointer for an object that gets moved around in memory, which causes that pointer to become a dangling pointer, and then accessing the no-object-there dangling pointer.  That pointer will only be valid as long as no mutating operation (e.g., `insertNode`) occurs, and only *may* be still valid depending on not-in-your-control factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector` is not a node-based container; therefore after `push_back` or `emplace_back` invocations, if new `size` exceeds old `capacity`, a total reallocation of vector occurs, leading to invalidation of all pointers and iterators previously referencing the vector.
Since you are using a vector - with its contiguous memory allocation - you can benefit from its random access property and store indice (instead of pointers) to elements:

```
std::size_t Graph::insertNode(Node n) {
    this->nodeArray.push_back(n);
    return size(this->nodeArray);
}
```

Because indice don't get invalidated due to vector growth; and they can be checked against `size` to ensure validity in case of possible shrinking operations(`erase`, `remove`,`clear`...). Moreover, the always invalid size would be `std:: numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`; because even if a vector can grow to the maximum index value, the index to last element would still be 1 below its size.

Answer (score 0):

Vector allocates space for a few objects. That's called `capacity`. When you `push_back()` an item, `size` of the vector changes but not `capacity`. At some time however, the `capacity` will no longer be sufficient to hold the `push_back`ed item and the vector will need to allocate new memory.

It will allocate some more memory, so that `capacity` is larger than `size` again. Some implementations double the amount each time, others increase by 50%. After enough storage is available, the vector will move the objects from their old location to the new location. Thus, their address changes. The old storage space is then `free`d or `delete`d and it's thus undefined behavior to access that location with any pointers you kept.

You can either re-think your algorithm or use a vector of pointers to Nodes, so that it's not the actual nodes that are being moved, but just their pointers.